# Error when using getItem with DynamoDB with the node aws-sdk library

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The following code produces this error message when trying to access my AWS DynamoDB table.  The table is called customers and the column is called email with a value of 'james@gmail.com'.  I've copied this code straight out of AWS examples available here https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples.  Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  I've wasted days on this, trying different things :-(

Any help appreciated.
Thanks,

**Error message**

```
{"message":"Expected params.Key to be a map","code":"InvalidParameterType","time":"2019-03-13T23:05:59.231Z"}
```

**NodeJs code**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

    // Set the region 
    AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});

    // Create DynamoDB document client
    var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

    var key = { email: 'james@gmail.com' };

    ddb.getItem({
       TableName: 'customers',
       Key: key
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        else {
          res.send(data);
        }
    });

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

**DynamoDB table**

[image]

**Another attempt**
I've also received this error message

```
{"message":"There were 20 validation errors:\n* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Key['email'] to be a structure\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in params.Key['email']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params.Key['email']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '2' found in params.Key['email']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '3' found in params.Key['email']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '4' found in params.Key['email']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '5' found in params.Key['email']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '6' found in
```

**Update**

```
 var key = { email: 'james@gmail.com' };

    ddb.getItem({
       TableName: 'customers',
       Key: key
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        else {
          res.send(data);
        }
    });
```

**Update**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

    AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
    var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

    var params = {
      TableName: 'customers',
      Key: {
        'email': {S: 'james@gmail.com'}
      },
    };

    ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

**Error result**

```
{"message":"The provided key element does not match the schema","code":"ValidationException","time":"2019-03-14T19:26:13.602Z","requestId":"EIGKLLNEJR2DKSET6787JHQLC7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":46.10177725769697}
```

Comment: I have completely missed that you are not using DocumentClient but DynamoDB service. Check updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2nd EDIT** : I have completely missed that you are not using DocumentClient (as pointed out Vladyslav Ulenko), so updated answer below for completeness.

---

You have two options:

**First option** use DynamoDB service object with `getItem` method like this:

```
...
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var params = {
  TableName: 'customers',
  Key: {
    'email': {S: 'james@gmail.com'} . // <-- pay attention to data type 'S'  
  },
};

ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.send(data);
    }
});
```

DynamoDB Data (attribute value) types are specified  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) (look for table Marshalling/Unmarshalling mapping.

**Second option** is to use `DocumentClient`. In this scenario you *don't have to worry about marshaling and un-marshaling request/response data* (DynamoDB value to/from JavaScript type). In this case your code is like this:

```
...

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});


var params = {
 TableName: 'customers',
 Key: {'email': 'james@gmail.com'}
};

docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.send(data);
    }
});
...
```

---

**I would suggest** you go with the `DocumentClient` instead of `DynamoDB'`getItem` operation as it completely handles all data conversion!

If you don't you would ALSO need to take care of response data types, eg:

```
data.Items.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      console.log(element.FristName.S + " " + element.LastName.S);
    });
```

not sure if you want to that

---

**3rd EDIT** : 
Now that you have done the above  you are getting error:

`"The provided key element does not match the schema"`

This means that the Key you used is not the same as the key defined on your schema, again from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html):

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.

Check the keys on your Table Details (example)
[image]

and make sure you put all keys mentioned there in your key parameter

Again as Vladyslav pointed out in comment section of his answer, if you need to find an item using the attribute that is not your primary key, you need to use [`scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) operation instead of `getItem`. You can find sample in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html)

Comment: made this change (see update in question) but still experiencing an error?

Comment: James - you are still missing data type - as you are using DynamoDB service and not DocumentClient. Updated answer for completeness

Comment: I'm trying now, I've updated the question with what I've tried (option 1 with AWS.DynamoDB) but I get the error "The provided key element does not match the schema"

Comment: @James - that is new issue :) keep updating your question is going to be very confusing for people to follow btw... Updating Answer

Comment: I can "close" this question if that's best?  Feels strange as I'm still not able to perform a simple query but I'll close it and post something new - thanks!

Comment: What are the keys defined in your schema?

Comment: Primary partition key id (String), Primary sort key -

Comment: That means that in your database in order to find 'by' email you need to use `scan` operation, `get` can only be used with Primary Key - in your case `id`

Comment: Ah ok!  Let me try it!

Comment: finally!  Crikey that was hard.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `DynamoDB` like `DocumentClient`. If you switch your line `var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});` to `var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();`, your queries will work.

With plain DynamoDB class instance you should also specify data types of your keys manually, you can find the reference to data types [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property). However, with DocumentClient class instance, the very class is responsible for data mapping between JS types and DynamoDB types. You can find this info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) in the Overview section.

Comment: You are right I've completely missed that he is not using DocumentClient but DynamoDB service. I have updated my answer for completeness as I see he is still missing some things...

Comment: I've made the change (see latest update in my question) but I get an error?

Comment: Now it looks like your query is wrong. Does your primary key consist of partition key and range key, or only partition key?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that with DynamoDB you can `get` only over a partition key. For everything else you should use `scan` or better global secondary index on some field and `query` over it

Comment: The table has 3 columns, id, email and username.  The email and username are strings.  I haven't looked at AWS databases before so I'll have a look at scanning tables

Comment: I see. Then your option is to put a GSI over `email`, if you are going to query over it a lot. DynamoDB is a very quirky database - keep that in mind. If your request can't be fulfilled with `query` or `getItem`, you are forced to use `scan`, which is very expensive. Design your schemes carefully and you're going to have a nice performance and small bill :)

Comment: So what do you reckon for high performance low cost, EC2 with sql/ mongo/ mysql manually installed or make use of DynamoDB/ DocumentDB?

Comment: It really depends on your application, there's no silver bullet. If your data can be modeled via NoSQL, because you know your queries in advance - go with NoSQL and denormalize your data according to the queries. If you feel like it's better to model a real world in your database - go with any SQL database you're the most experienced with. However, one giant benefit of DynamoDB is that you don't scale it, AWS does it for you.